# Formatting a text file of strings to be readable

Tags: python, string, parsing, text-files

I am trying to format this data file in a way that is presentable. The raw data is:

```
       Sodium
            Specimen insufficient for test(s)
       Potassium
            Specimen insufficient for test(s)
       Chloride
            Specimen insufficient for test(s)
       Bicarbonate
            Specimen insufficient for test(s)
       Urea
            Specimen insufficient for test(s)
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Creatinine                              116 H    umol/L                    64 - 104
       eGFR (MDRD formula)                     >60      mL/min/1.73 m2
            MDRD-derived estimation of GFR may significantly underestimate true GFR
            in patients with GFR > 60 mL/min/1.73m^2.  It may also be unreliable in
            the case of: age <18 years or >70 years; pregnancy; serious co-morbid
            conditions; acute renal failure; extremes of body habitus/unusual diet,
            gross oedema. The MDRD-eGFR used here does not employ an ethnic factor
            for race.

            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Calcium                                2.44      mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.55
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Magnesium                              0.88      mmol/L                  0.63 - 1.05
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Inorganic phosphate                    1.47 H    mmol/L                  0.78 - 1.42
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Total protein                            77      g/L                       60 - 78
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Albumin                                  48      g/L                       35 - 52
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Total bilirubin                           8      umol/L                     5 - 21
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Conjugated bilirubin (DBil)               1      umol/L                     0 - 3
       Alanine transaminase (ALT)
            Specimen insufficient for test(s)
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Aspartate transaminase (AST)             26      U/L                       15 - 40
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Alkaline phosphatase (ALP)               61      U/L                       53 - 128
            Authorised by xx  on 04/07/2015  at 17:02
       Gamma-glutamyl transferase (GGT)         18      U/L               <68
       Thyroid stimulating hormone (TSH)
            Specimen insufficient for test(s)
       Thyroxine (free T4)
            Specimen insufficient for test(s)
            Authorised by xx  on 02/07/2015  at 08:23
       White Cell Count             9.75   x 109/L                              3.92 - 10.40
       Red Cell Count               5.29   x 1012/L                             4.19 - 5.85
       Haemoglobin                  15.9   g/dL                                 13.4 - 17.5
       Haematocrit                 0.474   L/L                                 0.390 - 0.510
       MCV                          89.6   fL                                   83.1 - 101.6
       MCH                          30.0   pg                                   27.8 - 34.8
       MCHC                         33.5   g/dL                                 33.0 - 35.0
       RDW                          13.6   %                                    12.1 - 16.3
       Platelet Count                217   x 109/L                               171 - 388
       MPV                          10.0   fL                                    7.1 - 11.0
       Neutrophils                 65.60   %              6.40   x 109/L        1.60 - 6.98                                                                32.00 - 76.00
       Lymphocytes                 25.90   %              2.53   x 109/L        1.40 - 4.20                                                                   18.00 - 56.00
       Monocytes                    5.60   %              0.55   x 109/L        0.30 - 0.80                                                                    4.00 - 12.00
       Eosinophils                  0.50   %              0.05   x 109/L        0.00 - 0.95                                                                    0.00 - 8.00
       Basophils                    0.20   %              0.02   x 109/L        0.00 - 0.10                                                                    0.00 - 2.00
       "Other" Cells                2.10   %              0.20   x 109/L
Mark all unread as read Mark all unviewed as viewed
Print Report
```

I have no idea how to get rid of the whitespace in front of each string, and how to save the data on the next line.

I tried:

```
fin = open( 'results.txt', "r" )
lines = fin.read()
fin.close()
# test it ...
data = ""
for line in lines:
    data = data + line.strip();
print data
```

But it gives me this:

```
SodiumSpecimeninsufficientfortest(s)PotassiumSpecimeninsufficientfortest(s)ChlorideSpecimeninsufficientfortest(s)BicarbonateSpecimeninsufficientfortest(s)UreaSpecimeninsufficientfortest(s)AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Creatinine116Humol/L64-104eGFR(MDRDformula)>60mL/min/1.73m2MDRD-derivedestimationofGFRmaysignificantlyunderestimatetrueGFRinpatientswithGFR>60mL/min/1.73m^2.Itmayalsobeunreliableinthecaseof:age<18yearsor>70years;pregnancy;seriousco-morbidconditions;acuterenalfailure;extremesofbodyhabitus/unusualdiet,grossoedema.TheMDRD-eGFRusedheredoesnotemployanethnicfactorforrace.AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Calcium2.44mmol/L2.15-2.55AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Magnesium0.88mmol/L0.63-1.05AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Inorganicphosphate1.47Hmmol/L0.78-1.42AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Totalprotein77g/L60-78AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Albumin48g/L35-52AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Totalbilirubin8umol/L5-21AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Conjugatedbilirubin(DBil)1umol/L0-3Alaninetransaminase(ALT)Specimeninsufficientfortest(s)AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Aspartatetransaminase(AST)26U/L15-40AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Alkalinephosphatase(ALP)61U/L53-128AuthorisedbyIMMofokengon04/07/2015at17:02Gamma-glutamyltransferase(GGT)18U/L<68Thyroidstimulatinghormone(TSH)Specimeninsufficientfortest(s)Thyroxine(freeT4)Specimeninsufficientfortest(s)AuthorisedbyMJModungoaon02/07/2015at08:23WhiteCellCount9.75x109/L3.92-10.40RedCellCount5.29x1012/L4.19-5.85Haemoglobin15.9g/dL13.4-17.5Haematocrit0.474L/L0.390-0.510MCV89.6fL83.1-101.6MCH30.0pg27.8-34.8MCHC33.5g/dL33.0-35.0RDW13.6%12.1-16.3PlateletCount217x109/L171-388MPV10.0fL7.1-11.0Neutrophils65.60%6.40x109/L1.60-6.9832.00-76.00Lymphocytes25.90%2.53x109/L1.40-4.2018.00-56.00Monocytes5.60%0.55x109/L0.30-0.804.00-12.00Eosinophils0.50%0.05x109/L0.00-0.950.00-8.00Basophils0.20%0.02x109/L0.00-0.100.00-2.00"Other"Cells2.10%0.20x109/LMarkallunreadasreadMarkallunviewedasviewedPrintReport
```

And surely theres a better way to use the tab spaces and newlines to format the text? What am I missing?

Comment: Hint: if you want `data` to be more than one line, you probably need a `+ "\n"` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `line.strip()` you are stripping away all of the whitespace from the beginning and end of the string *including the newline*. So when you `data = data + line.strip()` you are creating the long string without newlines that you see when you print it. If you just want to print the lines without their leading whitespace you could you could either just strip that off:

```
for line in lines:
    data = data + line.lstrip()
print data
```

Or you could just print out the stripped lines as you strip them (print will put a newline back in):

```
for line in lines:
    print line.strip()
```

P.S. Don't put semicolons at the end of your Python statements.